# I'm trying to question a regular expression match

Tags: java, regex

'[loc]' must be included at the beginning and any character after it does not matter. How do I express it in a regular expression?
ex)

```
>>> [loc]korea
true
>>> [loc] 
false // (One or more strings must follow [loc])
>>> [lll]seoul
false
>>> busan 
false
```

I used Java and I can't really think of it. Ask for help, brothers

```
            String pattern = "\\[(loc)\\]"; 
            String val = "[loc]seoul"; 
            String val2 = "[loc]";
            String val3 = "seoul";
        
            boolean regex = Pattern.matches(pattern, val);
            System.out.println(regex);
            boolean regex2 = Pattern.matches(pattern, val2);
            System.out.println(regex2);
            boolean regex3 = Pattern.matches(pattern, val3);
            System.out.println(regex3);
```

Comment: What about `String pattern = "\\[loc\\].+"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you have some string, a keyword, that must appear at the start of a string. In that case, you need to `Pattern.quote` to escape any special chars that need escaping and use the `.+` pattern to match **one or more chars**. (You may also consider the `.*` pattern to match any *zero or more* chars if your first question sentence is correct and you do not care what is after `[loc]`.) To also match line breaks, that `.` does not match by default, you need pass the `Pattern.DOTALL` option, or prepend your pattern with `(?s)` inline modifier.

The solution will look like

```java
List<String> vals = Arrays.asList(
    "[loc]seoul", "[loc]", "seoul"
);
String keyword = "[loc]";
String pattern = Pattern.quote(keyword) + ".+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
for (String val : vals) {
    System.out.println(val + ": \"" + p.matcher(val).matches() + "\"");
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/dPgC9o). Output:

```
[loc]seoul: "true"
[loc]: "false"
seoul: "false"
```

Answer (score -1):

Its easy.
The regex expression should be like `loc\w+`

For java, you can parse it as `loc\\w+`